# error: invalid operands to binary expression ('vector<int>' and 'int')

Tags: c++, algorithm, class, sorting, stdvector

Given an array of `2n` elements, pair it in n elements and then find the sum of the minimum element in each pair and then maximize the sum. I wrote a class for this:

```
class Solution 
{
public:
    int sum = 0, n;

    int arrayPairSum(vector<int>& nums)
    {
        sort(nums, nums + 2 * n);
        for (i = 0; i < 2 * n; i = i + 2) 
        {
            sum = sum + nums[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }
};
```

but its showing me following error.

```
Line 5: Char 23: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('vector<int>' and 'int')
        sort(nums,nums+2*n);
                  ~~~~^~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_6
```

How should I remove this error?

Answer (score 2):

The error is from this line

```
sort(nums, nums+2*n);
           ^^^^^^^^^
```

here you are trying to add `2*n` to the vector of `int`s (i.e. `nums`). This is not defined, and hence the compiler error.

You need to pass the iterators to the `std::sort`.

```
#include <algorithm>

std::sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());
```

In addition, be aware in the condition of the `for`-loop that,

```
for(i=0; i<2*n; i=i+2) 
         ^^^^^
```

`n` must be initialized and `2*n` must be less than or equal to `nums.size()` (i.e. size of the vector `nums`). Otherwise, your code will have [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

---

Also, do not practice with `using namespace std;`. See here for more:

[Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Answer (score 0):

`sort(nums, nums+2 * n)` would works if `nums` was pointer or iterator;

here it would be `sort(nums.begin(), nums.begin() + 2 * n);`

but `nums.begin() + 2 * n` presupposes some relationship between `nums` and `n` which can probably be removed using `nums.size()` instead.